# Undefined symbol for i386 architecture and ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I inherited a project developped 3 years ago with ios 5 and 6 (target deployment), the project was never updated (eg. UI = iOS6).
When I launch the project with xcode 5.x or the latest version I always get this error after I set the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO` because this error :

First error if `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES`

> No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active
>   arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).

Second error if `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO`

```
 Undefined symbol for i386 architecture
       "_OBJC_CLASS _ $ _ UserDefaults", referenced from:
           objc-class-ref in SerializableObject.o
    ld: symbol (s) not found for i386 architecture
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Where is the `UserDefaults` class; in your source tree?

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks to you I understood the error . This file (and several others) are in a folder outside the project (but present in the tree of the project) so I removed the reference of this folder and drag & drop the "new" one in the project and now all work perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using two different architecture settings in the inherited project and the main project. make sure ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO to both the projects.